# How to develop python modules locally?

Tags: python, pypi

If we have a module i.e ModuleA, and then we have another ModuleB which depends on ModuleA, and we want modifications to ModuleA and ModuleB.

We both own moduleA and moduleB, how do actively develop against both if they are both being changed?

Should I be using a requirements-dev.txt which points to a fork of moduleA in moduleB. Then ensure this isn't committed to source control, and have a requirements.txt point to the artifact in our private PyPi instance?

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: If you want to be able to develop and release them independently, then you need to maintain backwards compatibility in ModuleA.

Comment: Thats fine but how do I write code in my local version of ModuleA and load it in my local version of b